# How to handle a tree given in an array of pairs?

Tags: input, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, computer-science

I'm struggling with finding the best of handling tree problems where the input is given as an array/list of pairs.

For example a tree is given as input in the format:
[(1,3),(1,2),(2,5)(2,4),(5,8)]
Where the first value in a pair is the parent, and the second value in a pair is the child.

I'm used to being given the root in tree problems. How would one go about storing this for problems such as "Lowest Common Ancestor"?

Comment: How you store it depends on the programming language. Please provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which problem you need to solve. For the problem of finding the lowest common ancestor of two nodes, you'll benefit most from a structure where you can find the parent of a given node in constant time. If it is already given that the nodes are numbered from 1 to *n* (without gaps), then an array is a good structure, such that `arr[child] == parent`. If the identifiers for the nodes are not that predictable, then use a hashmap/dictionary, such that `map.get(child) == parent`.

Comment: Any feedback on this answer, @kpok?

Comment: Hey trincot! Yes using a dictionary with child as a key and parent as value cleared this up for me completely! It's a common interview question I've been dealing with but hadn't had the input formatted yet in this way. Sorry I'm a very new StackOverflow user so can't upvote you yet. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I see that now haha. Thanks again